# Jquery error placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a form validated using jquery validate plugin.
The form consists of 3 columns and several rows like below

```
+______+____________+________________+
|Title |input field |error placement | 
+------+------------+----------------+
```

the normal error placement is

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                     error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
                 },
```

but I want to display elements in a `<td>` or `<div>` having name and id as `"errorbox"`, located on the first blank row.

How should I modify the syntax to do this??

Thanks in advance.. :)

blasteralfred

Comment: could you add the name of the plugin that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  error.appendTo($('#errorbox'));
},
```

However, I’d suggest looking at the errorContainer option as this probably does more what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Umh, both wrong.

Simply do a find.

Eg.

```
if(element.hasClass("myInputClass")) {
    error.appendTo(element.parents('tr').siblings().children().find('#errorbox'));
}
```

Wouldnt recommend using an ID though, as it wont be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's:

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element){
  $(".something_class_here").text("Your customer error");
}
```